# Make ObjectAnimator animation go back by five seconds (in Android Studio; using Kotlin)

Tags: android-studio, kotlin

There is a ten-second progress bar timer in my app. I used ObjectAnimator.ofInt to code the progress bar's countdown.

Here is the issue: I would like to give the user the option to go back by five seconds every time they press a button, but I have not found any function I could use to do that.

```kotlin
      
        val goBackFiveSeconds: Button = findViewById(R.id.goBackFive)

        var durationOfTimer: Long

        var progressBar: ProgressBar = findViewById(R.id.gameTimer)
        progressBar.max =1000
        val currentProgress = 1000

        val exampleProgBar = ObjectAnimator.ofInt(progressBar,"progress",currentProgress)

        durationOfTimer = 10000
        exampleProgBar.setDuration(durationOfTimer) //40,000 milliseconds = 40 seconds
        exampleProgBar.start()


        goBackFiveSeconds.setOnClickListener{
            //make animation go back by five seconds
        }
```

Something that I tried was:

```kotlin
  goBackFiveSeconds.setOnClickListener{
            exampleProgBar.setDuration(durationOfTimer + 5000)
        }
```

My thought process here was that if I increased the time by five seconds, that would essentially be the same thing as going back by five seconds. Unfortunately, this did not work well.

Is there maybe an ObjectAnimator function that can go back a few seconds? Or maybe you might have some other idea as to how I could achieve this? Thanks!